# Read UDID from Iphone with javascript on mobile safari

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c

How can I Read UDID from Iphone with javascript on mobile safari?

Comment: possible duplicate of [get iphone ID in web app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968323/get-iphone-id-in-web-app)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Update 2:**

Since the site below is dead already, this discussion thread in apple.com's forum has the diagnosis and source code on how did that site retrieve the UDID thru mobileconfig.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3089948?start=0&tstart=0

---

**Update**: the site mentioned in this answer is no longer on-line; it's now just a placeholder full of ads. Leaving original message below for reference.

---

Open http://whatismyudid.com/ in your iOS device

it is possible through mobileconfig ([Over-the-Air Profile Delivery and Configuration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html))

http://whatismyudid.com/device/start   <- download their mobileconfig and take a look

Comment: That site no longer exists; it's now a placeholder full of ads.

Comment: Sorry about that, updated the answer to point to a relevant source of getting UUID thru mobileconfig.

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible, and it never will be, unless the user explicitly installs policy configurations.

Comment: @Jeff: Only if the user explicitly installs that policy.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post, but I just want to share an implementation of [@powerj1984's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17411496/2931699) in php and ready to use that I found here :

https://github.com/hunk/get-UDID

It worked for me.

As I said it's an implementation, refer to [@powerj1984's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17411496/2931699) for detailed explanation.

Hope it will helps someone.