# Windows Phone Equivalent to iOS's .mobileconfig

Tags: ios, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, mdm

I'm trying to retrieve the UDID of a windows phone device without installing an app.  Apparently you can do this for iOS devices by sending users a signed .mobileconfig file that installs a webclip that tacks on the device's UDID as a querystring parameter.

See: [Read UDID from Iphone with javascript on mobile safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072240/read-udid-from-iphone-with-javascript-on-mobile-safari)

I'd like to determine if something like this is possible on Windows Phone (either 7 or ideally 8).  Basically e-mail a file to users that installs a live tile that links to a site that has the UDID tacked on the querystring.

Comment: I don't see the benefits of using UDID over something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, unfortunately there is nothing like this to my knowledge ... I'd love to be proven wrong though :P

Comment: That is correct. The most you will get from a user visiting a web page from a Windows Phone is a user agent string.

Comment: Not even in WP8?  It seems to be much more enterprise friendly.