# How does FreeMyApps work?

Tags: iphone, ios

FreeMyApps install a mobileconfig file on iOS device to register this device, and get this device's info(especially UDID).

Then download and install a recommended app on this device in FreeMyApps, credits added.

I guess when the downloaded app opened, device's info had also been sended to FreeMyApps' server. But app can't get device's UDID, what did the app send to server? How do the server decide whether this app-installed device is the same device which registered with a mobileconfig?

And suggest is grateful!
Best regards

Comment: By the UUID... an app can access that.

Comment: @Linuxios Isn't a new UUID generated at every call CFUUIDCreateString? I mean UUID can't represent a device. If I didn't understand the meaning of UUID, please tell me, thanks. Sorry for my poor English

Comment: Every Apple device has a specific, unchanging UUID.

Comment: @Linuxios yeah I think it's something called "UDID". But how to get UDID in an app while `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]` is deprecated? If I use `[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]`, could my app be in store?

Comment: You need `identifierForVendor` instead. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836225/ios6-udid-what-advantages-does-identifierforvendor-have-over-identifierforadve).

Comment: @Linuxios Thanks! I think `identifierForAdvertising` is a good choice. But how FreeMyApp's web app (since it's a web page, not a native app) get the `identifierForAdvertising` of device?

Comment: Here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968323/get-iphone-id-in-web-app

Comment: Hey any luck with this ? I need to read IDFA , or IFA or any other ID in safari which could also be read in a native app. I see UDID is possible in safari but not in native app. So i really need some common Unique identifier.

Comment: @i.jameelkhan use openurl jumps from your app to your server, give your server some params, then server returns the config file. After user install it, redirect to a registed scheme of your app with HTTP code 301 (302 will not work).